# Access multiple arrays across different pages using Vue.JS

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, vue.js, vuejs2

I have a fixed JSON array that contains 3 sets of data. I want to access a different array for each webpage I have and maybe access multiple arrays on a page at some point.

How can I access specific arrays in a JSON file with Vue? I have tried `<h2>{{items[0].page1}}</h2>` but nothing returns.

I have put an example of the 3 page demo at the link below:

https://arraydemo.netlify.com

```
<body>
<!-- Page List -->
<div class="container text-center mt-5" id="app">
    <h1 class="display-4">Vue Page Output:</h1>
    <h2>{{items[0].page1}}</h2>
</div>
<div class="container text-center mt-5">
    <h3>Other Pages</h3>
    <a href="products.html">Products</a>
    <a href="contactus.html">Contact Us</a>
</div>
<!-- /.container -->

<script type="text/javascript">
    const app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: {
        items: []
    },
    created: function () {
        fetch('test.json')
        .then(resp => resp.json())
        .then(items => {
            this.items = items
        })
    }
    });
</script>
</body>
```

JSON

```
[
    [
    {
        "page1": "Company Name"
    }
    ],
    [
    {
        "products": "Product List"
    }
    ],
    [
    {
        "contactus": "Contact Us at Acme Corp"
    }
    ]
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have an array of arrays:

```
[
    [{
        "page1": "Company Name"
    }], ...
```

You are trying to access the object before reach it, try: `<h2>{{items[0][0].page1}}</h2>`

Comment: Excellent, that's done it. The JSON that is delivered to us is in this format, so it does make the expressions look a bit ugly. I suppose I could merge those arrays but this seems to work fine. Thanks